# Part 2, Remove All From String problem in python

Tags: python

I can't figure out what I need to add to make my code work, this is what I have:

```
my_string = input("Enter a word: ")
part_to_remove = input("Enter a part of the word to remove: ")

def remove_all_from_string(my_string):
    while my_string != "bas":
        index = my_string.find(part_to_remove)
        return index

print remove_all_from_string(my_string)
```

I can't figure out what to add next, the test cases tells me to

1. Use the find function
2. Use a while loop
3. Use string concatenation
4. Use string indexing
5. Use the len function
6. Test the code with "bananas"
7. Test the code by replacing "na"
8. With the specified test info your code should return "bas"

I don't know what I could possibly do to match these and still make the code work

Comment: Does you assignment require to use ALL of the tools  in 1 -5 of your list, or ONLY ANY of 1 - 5, in order to accomplish the goal in #8?

Comment: NateB It requires all of the things.

Comment: You need to ask specific questions here. This looks like homework, so you should be clarifying with your instructor, not here. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the replace function of strings:

```
my_string = input("Enter a word: ")
paet_to_remove = input("Enter a part of the word to remove: ")

my_string = my_string.replace(paet_to_remove, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to write that code for you, but I will try to clarify some of the pointers:

- use `find` and string indexing (actually string slicing) to get the part of the string *before* the part to remove
- use `find`, `len`, and string slicing to get the part *after* the part to remove
- use string concatenation to combine them and replace the original string
- use `while` and `find` to continue while the part to remove exists in the string
- test the function with parameters `"bananas"` and `"na"`, and compare the result to `"bas"`, but do *not* "hard-code" any of that *into* your function

With those steps, you should be able to write the function on your own.

Comment: i just wrote the modified code :) Your response should do. :)

Comment: one addition I would do to @tobias_k response is to return the string rather than the index.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer of @kevin

```
my_string = input("Enter a word: ")
paet_to_remove = input("Enter a part of the word to remove: ")

print( ''.join(my_string.split(paet_to_remove)) )
```